# Why does an embedded ogg video work on localhost, but not on the web server?

Tags: video, embed, media

I have an ogg video which works just fine using the video tag when I run it on localhost in either Chrome or Firefox. However, when I try running the page on the server, the video player controls show up, but not the video.

I know the video is up on the server, because I have a download link that works which has the same exact path.. I'm at a loss.

```
<video width="800" controls preload>
   <source src="../VIDEOS/AddUser.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
   <object width="800" type="video/ogg" data="../VIDEOS/AddUser.ogg">
     <object classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11d3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" id="player" width="800" height="550"><param name="url" value="../VIDEOS/AddUser.wmv" /><param name="src" value="../VIDEOS/AddUser.wmv" /><param name="showcontrols" value="true" /><param name="autostart" value="true" />
        There was an error embedding the video. Please download the video to view.<br>
     </object>
   </object>
</video>
```

After fiddling around with it for a while, I've discovered that, according to the browser, the video simply isn't there. when I check the server, the file is up. However, when I navigate directly to the file within the browser, I get a file not found error.

Could this be an issue with my web host, or is there some other possible cause?

Comment: +1 for firebug - then maybe Wireshark?

Comment: This question is not relevant to embedded programming - the tag wiki explicitly says that the embedded tag does NOT apply to components embedded on a web page, see stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded.  The EMBED tag may be more relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to be looking for in firebug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that your host needs to add the OGG MIME type to the server.

The MIME type details can be found on http://xiph.org
The set up instructions will differ depending on whether the server is Apache or IIS

Comment: No probs. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the @mradbourne answer:
The extension-type mappings are stored in the *mime.types* file in the *httpd/conf* directory. If a pair extension-type is missed then you have that problem.

If you have access to the mime.types file search this lines:

```
video/mp4                   mp4 mp4v mpg4
video/ogg                   ogv
```

If you cannot modify your master configuration files, edit the `.htaccess` file located in your root directory (if not exist, feel free to create it). Add this lines:

```
AddType video/mp4 mp4 mp4v mpg4
AddType video/ogg ogv
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget Webm type file on yout .htaccess if you have one :)

`AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/ogg .ogv .ogg`

Answer (score -1):

I saw there is an OGG and a WMV video. Which of them are correct? Maybe you need to upload both the files.
If that doesn't work, check if the problem is the relative path: ../ trying to pass the absolute path http://.../ instead.

Comment: Actually, both are correct. The OGG is for Chrome and Firefox using the <video> tag, and the WMV is for IE using <object>. Both files are definitely on the server. I've uploaded them both many times. I've also tried navigating directly to both via the full, absolute path. The WMV pulls up fine, the OGG appears to be missing despite the fact that it is in that location.